# how to prevent calling a function multiple times in Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following code:

```
$('#main-button').click(function(){

    $('#button').click(function(){
        alert('something');
    });
});
```

Whenever I click the #main-button, say 3 times, and then click the #button, 3 popup boxes appears. How can I prevent this, so no matter how many times the #main-button is clicked, only 1 popup box will appear when the #button is clicked?

Comment: That's what you've told it to do - every time `main-button` is clicked, add _another_ event handler to `button`...

Comment: When you click on `main-button` you attach an event handler to your `button`. If you click three times your main button, you will attach three handler to your button. That's why 3 alert appears. You can prevent this by declaring a global boolean. when clicking the main button, check if the boolean is set to true. If not, attach the handler and set the boolean to true. Next click on main-button won't add a new handler to your button

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Or you can use this code:

```
$('#main-button').click(function(){

    $('#button').unbind("click").click(function(){
        alert('something');
    });
});
```

**Update #1**

The `unbind` was deprecated as of jQuery 1.7. Use `off` method instead.

Answer (score 5):

Use jQuery [one](http://api.jquery.com/one/) ,or explain what you are trying to do, there can be a better solution.

```
$('#main-button').click(function(){

    $('#button').one('click',function(){
        alert('something');
    });
});
```

For example, if your issue is like `#button` appears only when you click `#main-button` then use delegation at appropriate level using jquery [on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/) .(I am using delegation from document as your example is not clear)

```
$('#main-button').click(function(){

});


$(document).on('click','#button',function(){
   alert('something');
});
```

Comment: Ok, I assumed first click showed a popup and secong click is in popup, so both clicks are always done in workflow. I have provided a second solution if this is not the case.

Answer (score 1):

if you want to show the pop up only for the #button click, why are you putting the #button click function inside of the #main-button click function?

you can use them separately;

```
$('#main-button').click(function(){

});


$('#button').click(function(){
   alert('something');
});
```

Answer (score 1):

The solution is right there. Your event handler for the `#main-button` assigns a click handler to the other button every time you click it. Thus, you get X alerts.

Two possible quick fixes, both not elegant but just to show you where it goes wrong:

```
var isAssigned = false;
$('#main-button').click(function(){
    if (!isAssigned) {
        $('#button').click(function(){
            alert('something');
        });
    }
    isAssigned = true;
});
```

or

```
function myHandler() {
    $('#button').click(function(){
        alert('something');
    });
}

$('#main-button').click(function(){
    $('#button').off('click', myHandler);
    $('#button').on('click', myHandler);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Either write :

```
$('#button').click(function(){
    alert('something');
    return false;
});
```

Or,

```
$('#button').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefualt();
    alert('something');
});
```

I hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution is to set a variable outside of the button and then change the value the first time it's clicked

```
var clicked = 0;
$('#button').click(function(){
  if(clicked === 0) {
    alert('something');
    clicked = 1;
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

War10ck:
That's true, 
have updated code & fiddle.

The best solution would be just to unbind click event when link was clicked.

```
$(function() {
    $('#link').on('click', function() {
        if (!$(this).data('processing')) {
            $(this).data('processing', true);
            alert('A was clicked!!');
            $(this).data('processing', false);
        }
    });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/6jsgs/

Comment: You're fiddle only works for the first time the link is clicked. The alert only appears once because you immediately unbind it.